# How do you specify if storage should be local or session when using VueUse?

Tags: vue.js, vueuse

How do you specify if storage should be local or session when using VueUse?

It doesn't seem to mention it in the docs https://vueuse.org/core/usestorage/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The third argument to `useStorage()` specifies the storage to use. It uses [`window.localStorage`](https://github.com/vueuse/vueuse/blob/9b23828/packages/core/useStorage/index.ts#L135) by default.

To use session storage, pass [`window.sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) as the storage argument:

```js
useStorage(
  'my-storage-key',
  myInitialValue,
  window.sessionStorage, 
)
```